# Creating dynamic list variable with repeat command

Tags: loops, comma-separated-list

I need to create a list in LaTeX with *n* people and their respective sex:

```
\adduser[M]{Pedro Jose}
\adduser[M]{John Scar}
\adduser[F]{Leila Brew}
...
\adduser[F]{Larissa Yik}
```

When I compile it using LaTeX, I want it to produce something like that:

```
Pedro Jose is Male
John Scar is Male
Leila Brew is Female
...
Larissa Yik is Female
```

I tried primitive LaTeX repetition functions with a variable separated by `;`, but it does not work. Any idea?

---

@UPDATE

Steven solved the question.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\userlist{}
\newcommand*\adduser[2][]
  {\g@addto@macro\userlist{
    #2\ifx M#1 is male\fi\ifx F#1 is female\fi.\\
  }}
\makeatother

% User's to add
\adduser[M]{Pedro Jose}
\adduser[M]{John Scar}
\adduser[F]{Leila Brew}
\adduser[F]{Larissa Yik}

\begin{document}

{\noindent\textbf{User list:}}%

\noindent\userlist 

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is "dynamic" about the list?  Does the output have to occur at a different place in the document than the input?  Is the ordering of names subject to change?  Does the list require any random access, or is sequential sufficient?  etc...

Comment: Sequencial is suficient. Tried build a variable \edef\names{"Pedro Jose;John Scar;Leila Brew; ..."} with \loop  \substring{\names}{1}{10}  \repeat, but no sucess. Only get error

Comment: Do you need anything more than `\newcommand\adduser[2][]{#2\ifx M#1 is male\fi\ifx F#1 is female\fi.\\}` ?  And if so, why?

Comment: The main ideia is build something like \addcontentsline and \tableofcontents. Thanks again

Comment: The question that remains unanswered is how you intend to use this.  The notion of an `\addcontentsline` is required when the list regurgitation occurs **BEFORE** the individual items are specified (like a toc).  If the regurgitated list occurs either AS the items are defined or AFTER the items are defined, then `\addcontentsline` type approach is not needed and just adds unneeded complexity..

Comment: Thanks Steven, you solve the question.

\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\userlist{}
\newcommand*\adduser[2][]
  {\g@addto@macro\userlist{
    #2\ifx M#1 is male\fi\ifx F#1 is female\fi.\\
  }}
\makeatother

% User's to add
\adduser[M]{Pedro Jose}
\adduser[M]{John Scar}
\adduser[F]{Leila Brew}
\adduser[F]{Larissa Yik}

\begin{document}


{\noindent\textbf{User list:}}%

\noindent\userlist 

\end{document}

Comment: So, in this case, because the need for the list is **AFTER** the definition of the names, appending the names to a `\def` is an acceptable way to go about this, if you don't need to rearrange or edit the list.  Bravo!

Comment: yeah, thanks steve! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the [datatool](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool)-package and maintaining two databases:

- One database is used for adding entries.
  That database is to be saved to an external text-file at the end of the LaTeX-run.
  In the example below that database is called "usersinterim".
- Another database is used for iterating on entries.
  That database is created at the beginning of the LaTeX-run by loading the external-text-file created during the previous run.
  That database contains all data-entries that were added in the *previous* LaTeX-run.
  In the example below that database is called "users".

This way you can create lists of all users etc even before having a user added.

But you need to compile the document at least twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{atveryend}

\newcommand\DATABASEFILECreateIfNotExistent[1]{%
  \DTLifdbexists{#1}{}{%
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.#1}{%
      \DTLloaddb{#1}{\jobname.#1}%
    }{%
      \DTLnewdb{#1}%
    }%
  }%
  \DTLifdbexists{#1interim}{}{%
    \DTLnewdb{#1interim}%
    \AtEndDocument{%
      % This will save the interim-database to file with
      % the last \shipout. The last \shipout is triggered
      % by \end{document}/\enddocument.
      \DTLsavedb{#1interim}{\jobname.#1}%
    }%
    \AfterLastShipout{%
      % Check whether the content of the database-token-register
      % stemming from the database-file of the previous LaTeX-run
      % differs from content of the database-token-register
      % stemming from the database-file of the current LaTeX-run.
      % If so, something changed and you need to re-run LaTeX.
      % Probably this should be omitted with large databases.
      \begingroup
      \DTLgdeletedb{#1interim}%
      \DTLloaddb{#1interim}{\jobname.#1}%
      \edef\tempa{\the\csname dtldb@#1\endcsname}%
      \edef\tempb{\the\csname dtldb@#1interim\endcsname}%
      \ifx\tempa\tempb
        \endgroup
      \else
        \endgroup
        \csname @latex@warning@no@line\endcsname{%
           Database `#1' may have changed.
           Rerun to get listings of entries etc right%
         }%
      \fi
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\usercount{0}%
\newcommand\stepusercount{%
  \xdef\usercount{\number\numexpr\usercount+1\relax}%
}%
\newcommand\adduser[2][]{%
  \stepusercount
  \DATABASEFILECreateIfNotExistent{users}%
  \DTLnewrow{usersinterim}%
  {%
    \dtlexpandnewvalue
    \DTLnewdbentry{usersinterim}{primary key}{\usercount}%
  }%
  \DTLnewdbentry{usersinterim}{name}{#2}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{usersinterim}{gender}{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\GenderListOfAllUsers{%
  \DATABASEFILECreateIfNotExistent{users}%
  \DTLforeach{users}{\NameField=name, \GenderField=gender}{%
      \par\noindent
      \NameField
      \expandafter\lowercase\expandafter{\expandafter\ifx\GenderField}m%
        \space is male%
      \else
        \expandafter\lowercase\expandafter{\expandafter\ifx\GenderField}f%
          \space is female%
        \else
          's gender is not identified%
        \fi
      \fi
      .%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{List of all users:}\medskip

\GenderListOfAllUsers

\bigskip

\noindent\textbf{Some text.}

\bigskip

\adduser[M]{Pedro Jose}
\adduser[M]{John Scar}
\adduser[F]{Leila Brew}
\adduser[F]{Larissa Yik}
\adduser[?]{John Doe}
\adduser{Smith, John}

\noindent\textbf{List of all users:}\medskip

\GenderListOfAllUsers

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a powerful package. I'll test it tomorow! Thanks Diez